# Getting java.lang.NullPointerException in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I am trying to persist form data to database using spring MVC and hibernate but when calling the save method of hibernate session.getSession.save(s) it is returning NullPointerException.

Here is the code of my index.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome to Spring Web MVC project</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="insert.htm">
        <label>  Name:</label><input type="text" name="name"><br>
        <label> Id:</label><input type="text" name="id"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Enter">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the web.xml file

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And my dispatcher-servlet.xml is

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"  id="sessionFactory">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<property name="annotatedClasses">
    <list>
        <value>com.model.Student</value>
    </list>
</property>
<property name="hibernateProperties">  
<props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
</props>
</property>
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    p:url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:Xe"
    p:username="hibernate"
    p:password="hibernate"></bean>
   <bean id="hibernatetransactionManager"             class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>                
   </bean>
```

and here is my model class Student

```
package com.model;

import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Entity;


 @Entity
  public class Student {
  @Id    
  private int id;
  private String name;

  public int getId() {
    return id;
 }

 public void setId(int id) {
     this.id = id;
 } 

 public String getName() {
     return name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
     this.name = name;
 }

  }
```

And my controller is

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

@Autowired
    private Dao d;
@RequestMapping(value="/insert.htm",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView insert(HttpServletRequest req,Student s)
{
   String name=req.getParameter("name");
    int id=Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("id"));
    s.setId(id);
    s.setName(name);
   System.out.println(s.getName());
    d.save(s);
    return new ModelAndView("display","Student",s);

}
```

Here is my Dao

```
 @Repository
 public class Dao {
 @Autowired
 private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

 public int save(Student s)
   {

     /*Session s1=sf.openSession();
     s1.beginTransaction();
     int i=(Integer)s1.save(s);
     s1.getTransaction().commit();
     return i;*/
     int i=(Integer)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(s);
     return i;
     }
   }
```

The Exception i am getting at d.save(s) in MyController

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/Spring5]          
threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception
at com.controller.MyController.insert(MyController.java:30)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at s   un.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at  org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(Ha ndlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    at  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.jav a:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at  org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I am begginer to spring mvc please help me out .
i am getting Exception while calling insert i have used @Autowired also...

Comment: Which line is line 36 in `MyController`?

Comment: d.save(s) in controller class that is MyController

Comment: @Rahul You have SessionFactory reference named as sessionFactory but you are using sf for calling openSession() ?....Do you have two SessionFactory configured?...And also where have you initialized Student object?

Answer (score 2):

Unless the stacktrace you have posted is not accurate, then the null reference is your `Dao` in the controller. Are you sure it is being wired in correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for *NullPointerException* is: neither you are using *@ModelAttribute* for bean binding, nor you have created

```
Student s = new Student();
```

in case if you don't want *@ModelAttribute*.
You 
You are missing *@ModelA rrtibute* before the parameter *Student s* in the your controller code. If you use *@ModelAttribute* annotation for bean binding, you don't need to get the request parameters from request and populate the bean. Therefore remove the following:

```
String name=req.getParameter("name");
int id=Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("id"));
s.setId(id); /* Here you are setting a value with a reference wcich points to null */
s.setName(name); /* Here you are setting a value with a reference wcich points to null */
```

The Annotation *@ModelAttribute* automatically binds request parameters to the matching properties of the bean on which it is applied.

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @Autowired(required = true) 
    private Dao d;
    @RequestMapping(value="/insert.htm",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView insert(HttpServletRequest req,@ModelAttribute Student s)
    {
        System.out.println(s.getName());
        d.save(s);
        return new ModelAndView("display","Student",s);

    }
```

Edit: you have annotated the class Dao with *@Repository*. It will create a singleton object with name *dao*. If you want any other name except it, then use

```
@Repository(value ="d") 
 public class Dao{

}
```

Now you can autowire the instance *d* as you were doing

```
@Autowired (required = true) 
private Dao d;
```

In your case the autowired Dao instance is null because spring is unable to autowire a bean named *d*. Therefore, you are invoking the save method on null reference.

Comment: That doesn't seem right. The stacktrace indicates that his `Dao` is null -- nothing to do with the reference to the student.

Comment: Stack trace is indicating about NullPointerException at line no 36 in MyController class.

Comment: Right, and the only pointer being dereferenced in `d.save(s)` is the `Dao`.

Comment: I had done Changes by adding the @ModelAttribute parameter but still i am getting the same error that is NullPointerException

Comment: Hi Vaibhav thank u for your suggestions.The problem is still persisting with same NullPointerException .

Comment: Can you tell me where is line number 30 in your MyController class.

Comment: `@Autowired(required = true)
        private Dao d;` line no 30 is `d.save(s);`

Comment: Have you made both changes: @Repository(value ="d") as well as @ModelAttribute Student s??

Comment: If u have time please move into chat

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32407/discussion-between-rahul-and-vaibhav-raj)

Answer (score 0):

@Rahul, you are binding the data in Get Method but actually you should not do that in the GET method 
 when you are dealing with the form you should always Use POST method
i think it might help you :-)

```
@RequestMapping(value="/insert.htm",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView insert(HttpServletRequest req,@ModelAttribute Student s)
    {
        System.out.println(s.getName());
        d.save(s);
        return new ModelAndView("display","Student",s);

    }
```